# System.AggregateExeption while using Parallel.ForEach

Tags: c#, .net, windows, service, parallel.foreach

I am building this webcrawler to gather steam profile id from their search due to lack of better options.

It is supposed to run as a service but I can't make it work. If I copy the code and run it as a console application, it works perfectly.

I am new to windows service programming and using parallel tasks, so if theres anything else completely off or inefficient please enlighten me, but the problem at hand is more important.

I've tried to debug it using the eventviewer but I'm also new to that stuff, and I find it very tedious and not sure what to look for.

Below is the code that works in console application, but not as a windows service. Why does it only work in a console application?

```
public partial class SSIDGatherer : ServiceBase
{
    EventLog log;
    Thread t;

    public SSIDGatherer()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        if (!EventLog.SourceExists("SSIDGatherer"))
        {
            EventLog.CreateEventSource("SSIDGatherer", "SteamStats");
        }

        log = new EventLog();
        log.Source = "SSIDGatherer";
        log.Log = "SteamStats";
    }

    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        ServicePointManager.UseNagleAlgorithm = true;
        ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = true;
        ServicePointManager.CheckCertificateRevocationList = true;
        ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = 50;

        ThreadStart ts = new ThreadStart(Treading);

        try
        {
            t = new Thread(ts);
            t.Start();
        }
        catch (AggregateException agex)
        {
            string message = "";
            foreach (Exception ex in agex.InnerExceptions)
            {
                message += string.Format("Exception: {0} \n\nStack: {1}", ex.Message, ex.StackTrace);
            }

            log.WriteEntry(message, EventLogEntryType.Error);
        }
    }

    protected override void OnStop()
    {
        t.Abort();
    }

    private void Treading()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            //steam custom url allowed characters a-z 0-9 _ -
            string[] characters = new string[] { "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z", "0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "-", "_" };

            //for every combination you can do with 2 letters (which is minimum required for a player search)
            Parallel.ForEach(characters, characterX =>
            {
                Parallel.ForEach(characters, characterY =>
                            {
                                CrawlSteamIDs("http://steamcommunity.com/actions/Search?T=Account", characterX + characterY, 1);
                            });
            });
        }
    }

    private void CrawlSteamIDs(string baseUrl, string keyword, int page)
    {
        HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();

        try
        {
            string url = baseUrl + "&K=" + keyword + "&p=" + page;

            //Some steam urls redirect to https for no reason, as the data is also available on http.
            //Could be an error from steam, or an typo from me. Test it out later. For now, crudely replacing will have to do.
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(url.Replace("https:", "http:"));
            request.UserAgent = "Steam-Stats Web Crawler";
            request.Timeout = 20000;

            using (WebResponse response = request.GetResponse())
            {
                doc.Load(response.GetResponseStream());
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            log.WriteEntry("Timeout Error\nURL: " + baseUrl + "&K=" + keyword + "&p=" + page, EventLogEntryType.Error);
        }

        if (doc.DocumentNode.HasChildNodes)
        {
            //if the search returns any results otherwise just skip trying scanning
            if (doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//div[@id='resultsMsg']") == null)
            {
                    Parallel.ForEach(doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a[@class='linkTitle']"), link =>
                                {
                                    string href = link.Attributes["href"].Value;

                                    //get profiles with custom name enabled
                                    if (href.StartsWith("http://steamcommunity.com/id/"))
                                    {
                                        string steamID = href.Substring(29);

                                        DAL db = new DAL("DB");
                                        db.Addparameter("@SteamID", steamID, SqlDbType.NVarChar);
                                        db.ExecuteNonQuery("QueueGathererSteamID", true);
                                    }

                                    //get profiles using the steam64ID
                                    if (href.StartsWith("http://steamcommunity.com/profiles/"))
                                    {
                                        long steam64ID = Convert.ToInt64(href.Substring(35));

                                        DAL db = new DAL("DB");
                                        db.Addparameter("@Steam64ID", steam64ID, SqlDbType.NVarChar);
                                        db.ExecuteNonQuery("QueueGathererSteam64ID", true);
                                    }
                                });

                //crawl next page if available
                HtmlNode pagebtn = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//a[@class='pagebtn' and .='&gt;']");
                if (pagebtn != null)
                {
                    CrawlSteamIDs(baseUrl, keyword, page + 1);
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            log.WriteEntry("Error Loading HTML Page: " + doc.ToString() + "\nURL: " + baseUrl + "&K=" + keyword + "&p=" + page, EventLogEntryType.Error);

            //error loading page, try next page instead
            CrawlSteamIDs(baseUrl, keyword, page + 1);
        }
    }
}
```

The stack from eventviwer. The source is listed as .NET Runtime

> Application: SSIDGatherer.exe
>   Framework Version: v4.0.30319
>   Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
>   Exception Info: System.AggregateException
>   Stack:
>      at System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.ForWorker[[System._*Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]](Int32, Int32, System.Threading.Tasks.ParallelOptions, System.Action`1<Int32>, System.Action`2, System.Func`4<Int32,System.Threading.Tasks.ParallelLoopState,System.__Canon,System.__Canon>, System.Func`1, System.Action`1<System.__Canon>)
>      at System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.ForEachWorker[[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]](System.__Canon[], System.Threading.Tasks.ParallelOptions, System.Action`1, System.Action`2<System.__Canon,System.Threading.Tasks.ParallelLoopState>, System.Action`3, System.Func`4<System.__Canon,System.Threading.Tasks.ParallelLoopState,System.__Canon,System.__Canon>, System.Func`5, System.Func`1<System.__Canon>, System.Action`1)
>      at System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.ForEachWorker[[System.*_Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],[System._*Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]](System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1<System.__Canon>, System.Threading.Tasks.ParallelOptions, System.Action`1, System.Action`2<System.__Canon,System.Threading.Tasks.ParallelLoopState>, System.Action`3, System.Func`4<System.__Canon,System.Threading.Tasks.ParallelLoopState,System.__Canon,System.__Canon>, System.Func`5, System.Func`1<System.__Canon>, System.Action`1)
>      at System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.ForEach[[System.*_Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]](System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1<System.__Canon>, System.Action`1)
>      at SSIDGatherer.SSIDGatherer.Treading()
>      at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(System.Object)
>      at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
>      at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object)
>      at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()

Comment: Could you post the full text of the exception, including the stack trace and its inner exceptions?

Comment: Without a much shorter example that shows the problem or the exception details, it's almost impossible for anyone to tell you what's wrong without debugging the code themselves

Comment: Instead of posting the code that works, why not post a small snippet of the code that doesn't work.

Comment: If i knew what part was making the error I could handle that myself. The problem is I haven't got a single clue about what goes wrong. I've tried using a try catch at every Parallel.ForEach cathing Exeption and aggregateExeption but they never hit the try catches. I updated the post with the error from the eventview.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try putting a [Debugger.Launch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debugger.launch.aspx) in the OnStart of the service, that way you can step through the code and figure out where things are going wrong.

Comment: Thank you thank you, that made debuggning so much easier. Turns out that the problem was this:

The source 'SSIDGatherer' is not registered in log 'SteamStats'. (It is registered in log 'Application'.) " The Source and Log properties must be matched, or you may set Log to the empty string, and it will automatically be matched to the Source property.

How do I avoid this error? It seems to occur often. Maybe because I install/uninstall a lot?